# How does PHP's list function work?

Tags: php, function, internals

After recently answering a couple of questions here on SO that involved utilizing PHP's `list` function, I wondered, "**how in the world does that function actually work under the hood?**". I was thinking about something like using `func_get_args()` and then iterating through the argument list, and that's all nice and peachy, but then how in the world does the **assignment** part work?

```
 list(...) = array($x, $y, $z);
```

isn't this ^ evaluated first?

So to be precise, my question is how is the `list` function able to create scoped variables which get assigned to the not-yet evaluated array?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`list` is a *language construct*, not a function. It does not play by the rules of normal functions, it's more akin to an `if` or `for` (or `array()`, [as the manual states](http://php.net/list)), hard-coded into the PHP core.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to leave a comment? (You did bring by rep to a nice round number though, so, thanks, I s'pose.)

Comment: @stereofrog These things are officially called *language constructs* in PHP. Computer scientifically they may be operators, I'm sticking to PHP terminology here.

Comment: @stereofrog Oh well, I guess that's debatable. I guess it serves to mark the difference between something that's clearly an operator like `=` and something that looks more like a function but isn't, like `empty`. I'd agree that `list()=` would be an operator, but it's "official name" is `list()`, which works together with the `=` operator... Meh. That's PHP for ya, not very academic. :)

Comment: @stereofrog That debate wouldn't be cleared up by using different terms though, as both are *language constructs*. I think it's easier to understand for beginners this way (not that that's any less of a problem ;P).

Comment: @stereofrog If they'd do it correctly they'd use a syntax that doesn't resemble function calls but looks more like an operator to begin with. I'd guess that's the reason they don't call them operators, to not confuse people who can barely understand infix *operators*, let alone why `list() =` is called an "operator".